# Best way to achieve thread functionality in Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am doing the chat project in Java with Spring 3.2.

Normally in Java I can create a thread like this:

```
public class Listener extends Thread{
    public void run(){
         while(true){

         }
    }
}
```

and start the thread by `start()`.

But in `Spring 3.x` is there any special classes or any special way to achieve the thread functionality?

### My requirements:

I have 2 telecom domain servers. In my application I need to initialize the servers to create the protocol.

After the servers are initialized, I need to start two threads to listen the responses from the telecom domain servers.

What I have done was given below:

```
public class Listener extends Thread{
    public void run(){

       while(true){
           if(ServerOne.protocol != null){
                Message events = ServerOne.protocol.receive();
                   //Others steps to display the message in the view
           }
       }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the java thread functionality with the `quartz` ?

If possible which one is better ? if no means , what is the reason ?

Hope our stack members will give the better solution.

Comment: you can have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html chapter specially at @Scheduled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring's TaskExecutor is a good way to run these threads in a managed environment. You could refer to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html for some examples.

Comment: Shall I do these with the quartz ?

Answer (score 1):

Java has what you need. I advise against using Thread manually. You should always use something that manages the threads for you. Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800583/2542027

Answer (score 1):

You could use Spring's [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#threadPoolTaskExecutor)
You can define your executor as such in you configuration file

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" destroy- method="shutdown">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="2" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="10" />
</bean>

<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />
```

In your `Listener` you could have a method that does all the work in it and annotate this method with the @Async annotation. Ofcourse, `Listener` should also be Spring managed.

```
public class Listener{

    @Async
    public void doSomething(){

       while(true){
           if(ServerOne.protocol != null){
                Message events = ServerOne.protocol.receive();
                   //Others steps to display the message in the view
           }
       }

    }
}
```

Now everytime `doSomething` is called, a new thread will be created if there are less than `corePoolSize` number of threads being run by the executor. Once `corePoolSize` number of threads are created, every subsequent call to `doSomething` will create a new thread only if there are more than `corePoolSize` but less than `maxPoolSize` running (not idle) threads and the thread queue is full. More about pool sizes can be read in the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Note : While using @Async you might encounter the following exception if CGLIB library is not made available in your application.

```
Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
```

To overcome this without having to add CGLIB dependencies, you can create an interface `IListener` that has doSomething() in it and then have `Listener` implement `IListener`

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring 3, you can use @Schedule annotation:

```
@Service
public class MyTest {
  ...
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10)
  public getCounter() {...}
}
```

with `<context:component-scan base-package="ch/test/mytest">` and `<task:annotation-driven/>`  in the context file

Please refer to this tutorial:http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/