# Executor with limited thread count on demand

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I am looking for an `ExecutorService` that creates threads on demand up to a predefined limit and destroys idle threads after a keep alive time.

The following constructor creates a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with fixed thread count:

```
// taken from Executors.newFixedThreadPool()
new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

So I tried to create a `ExecutorService` this way:

```
// taken from Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, nThreads,
    CACHED_POOL_SHUTDOWN_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

But it doesn't work as expected, when `nThreads` are in use, the `Executor` does not enqueue new tasks but throws an `RejectedExecutionException`. I know I could implement a handler for that, but it didn't help me.

How can I create the `Executor` described ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an approach on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800583/748524) that does exactly what I need.
@assylias I recognized your answer and changed the queue implementation.

Now my code looks like this:

```
parallelExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
    CACHED_POOL_SHUTDOWN_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

parallelExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);   // this is the magic
```

It works like a fixed thread pool but these core thats are allowed to time out.

Answer (score 2):

If a new task can't be queued, a new thread is created, unless you have already reached the maximum core pool size. In your case, the queue can only contain one task at a time so if  you submit tasks quickly enough you reach the maximum pool size and get the exception.

It works with CachedThreadPool because the maximum core pool size is large (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

You need to use a different queue, for example a new `LinkedBlockingQueue` like in the the fixed threadpool example.

Side note: checking the implementation documentation can help understand the details. In particular, the `execute` method of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class has:

```
   /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     *
     * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
     * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
     * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
     * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
     * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
     * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
     *
     * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
     * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
     * and so reject the task.
     */
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But it may happen that thousands of tasks where enqueued and I don't want to create such a big queue.

Comment: @Stephan You need to do something with the task that can't be run (max pool size is used) and can't be enqueued (queue is full)... You can restrict the size of the queue but you will receive an exception once it is full.

Comment: That's true again. I removed the `capacity` parameter from the constructor of the queue, so it is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.