# Java thread pooled server using blocking I/O

Tags: java, networking, threadpool

I have implemented a server in Java, upon receiving data from some client it simply forwards the data to all other clients (including the sender). I'm happy with my OO-design, I wrap all sockets in classes that provide 'callbacks'. These are called when some data are ready (or when the socket closes) -- using this design I could easily implement a simple TLV protocol to atomically send packets: the callback is not called until a full packet is received.

Now, I use the `java.io` package blocking I/O calls to the socket streams (and make them appear 'asynchronous' through those callbacks). So I use threads inside my socket wrapper classes: when a socket is opened, that function returns a `Runnable` implementation that, when run, will do the blocking calls to the `InputStream`, buffer data and eventually call the callback.

=> In a client application, I simply launch this `Runnable` in a `Thread` instance, because it's just one thread.

=> In my server, I submit all `Runnable` implementations I get upon creating new sockets (i. e. when accepting new clients) into a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. (FYI: the callbacks of the sockets simply `put` the received packets in a `BlockingQueue`. A single, separate (non-pooled) "dispatcher" `Thread` instance constantly `take`s the packets from this queue and writes them to all sockets currently connected to the server.)

**QUESTION:** This all works great, however I'm unsure about my use of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, because the `Runnable` instances submitted are almost always blocking. Will the `ThreadPoolExecutor` react to this? Or will the pooled threads simply block? Because, if all pooled threads are all blocking while executing their `Runnable` and next, a new `Runnable` is submitted, then what? Suspend the new `Runnable`? That's not good, because then the newly connected client will have zero responsiveness until some older client disconnects. If by contrast the thread pool chooses to spawn a new thread to handle the `Runnable`, then I actually get a thread-per-client scenario.

I want the thread pool to 'preempt' the blocking threads and use them to handle other sockets, like an operating system that suspends I/O bound processes and doesn't schedule them again until their I/O is complete. Is that at all possible, or will I have to rewrite everything using `nio` in order to do this? (if `nio` is required, could you point out where I should start reading?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the `ThreadPoolExecutor`: it depends. An `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` will just create new threads for new Runnables. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1800317/3080094) and the accepted answer. But you will end up with a thread-per-client scenario.

`Nio` prevents the thread-per-client scenario (if there are many clients sending relative small messages with pauses in between, see also (the summary of) [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html)), I advice against trying to build your own `nio` clone.

Implementing `nio` from the ground up is not easy, a tutorial can be found [here](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/). It might be easier to use a `nio` server like [Netty](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html).

Another alternative is to use a technology designed to handle many clients that send and receive small messages. It takes some time to learn and setup, but I managed to get a [Tomcat WebSockets](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) server talking with a [Jetty WebSocket](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) client pretty quickly. A rewrite to use this technology could be less work.