# Difference in parameters of fixed and cached thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read various blogs and javadoc regarding fixed thread pool and cached thread pool and when to use one over the other. But, they have various constructors and I am not very clear about all the parameters like core pool size etc. What is the difference between a fixed thread pool(nThreads) and a cached thread pool with core pool size as nThreads. 
I want to know about all the parameters of their constructors.

Comment: Don't use the constructors, use the `Executors` utility class. For more information, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Comment: I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1800583/2071828) - it's a different question so not a dup, but the answer answers your question too.

Answer (score 1):

The methods on `Executors` are know as factory methods, rather than constructors.

A fixed thread pool has a fixed size, it is always the number of threads you tell it to be.

The cached pool, caches the threads it creates, it doesn't have a size, but rather it keeps track of the most threads it needed in the last minute, shutting down any threads which have not been used for a minute.