# Execute a continious task via ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, java.util.concurrent

Facing the problem with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Java.

How can I execute a continuous task using it? For example, I want to execute something like this:

```
    @Async
    void MyVoid(){
       Globals.getInstance().increment();
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" iteration # "+ Globals.getInstance().Iterator);
    }
```

I want it to run forever in 2 parallel asynchronous threads until the user sends a request to stop the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the "/stop" controller.

If I use this for **example:**

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("api/test")
    public class SendController {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executor =  new ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(5);
        boolean IsRunning = true;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/start_new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Callable<String> StartNewTask(@RequestBody LaunchSend sendobj) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Runnable runnable = () -> { MyVoid();};
            executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
            executor.setMaximumPoolSize(2);


            while (IsRunning) {
                executor.execute(runnable);
                System.out.println("Active threads: " + executor.getActiveCount());
            }


            return () -> "Callable result";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/stop", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Callable<String> StopTasks()  {
            executor.shutdown(); //for test
            if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != null &&  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != "anonymousUser") {
                executor.shutdown();
                return () -> "Callable result good";
            }
            else { return () -> "Callable result bad";}
        }
    }

public class ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public ErrorReportingThreadPoolExecutor(int nThreads) {
        super(nThreads, nThreads,
                0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable task, Throwable thrown) {
        super.afterExecute(task, thrown);

        if (thrown != null) {
            // an unexpected exception happened inside ThreadPoolExecutor
            thrown.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (task instanceof Future<?>) {
            // try getting result
            // if an exception happened in the job, it'll be thrown here
            try {
                Object result = ((Future<?>)task).get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                // the job get canceled (may happen at any state)
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // some uncaught exception happened during execution
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // current thread is interrupted
                // ignore, just re-throw
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

1. As I understood, a lot of tasks got submitted into the 'executor' queue within a few seconds and then the executor handled all them. (But I need each thread to wait before the current task ends and then submit the new one to the executor, I think.)
2. HTTP Requests to these controllers are forever "IDLE" until the next request comes, i.e. after sending a request to `/api/test/start_new` the controller's code executed tasks that are running, but the request is IDLE.

How can I do this in Java?

P.S. Spring MVC is used in the project. It has its own implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` - `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, but I am facing similar problems with it.

Comment: If you need to know when a task is completed, look at using `java.util.concurrent.Executors` to create an `ExecutorService`. `ExecutorService::submit` will return a `Future<T>` which you can use to tell when a task is completed. If you are using Java 8, also look at `CompletableFuture`, which is a new, nicer interface.

Comment: Do you mean continuous? or do you mean continual?

I would not normally use an `ExecutorService` to run a task that never ends. I would use a naked `Thread` for that.

On the other hand, I would use a `ScheduledExecutorService` (or something like it) to continually run a short-lived task at periodic intervals.

Comment: Your task object manipulates the executor to which it has been submitted.  That sounds like a really Bad Idea---too much coupling between your classes.  This seems like an XY problem:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: As i said, that i need is to: run the forever-repeating method in  multi-threading for on one user-request, finish all threads in other.

Comment: @jameslarge why not? CachedThreadPoolExecutor is a perfect fit for such task.

Comment: @Antoniossss, I don't know that class, and a google search turns up nothing.  Are you talking about the object returned by `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()`?  I don't think I would ever use that in real code.  I would not use it where I needed a thread pool because there is no way to limit how many simultaneous threads it will create.  And, I would not use it to start a permanent thread because, why go through a middle man when it's just as easy to do it yourself?

Comment: @jameslarge 1) Yes i was talking about that pool 2) you are not correct because you can set thread max count. You can confirm that if you check what is happening inside `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()`.

Comment: @Antoniossss, That's undocumented behavior.  The declared return type from `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()` is `ExecutorService`, and there is no `setMaximumPoolSize(n)` method declared in that type.  If you happen to know that the _actual_ type of the object is `ThreadPoolExecutor` and you cast it at run time, then everything will be fine...  Untill the day when somebody tries to deploy your code on a JRE that doesn't work that way.

Comment: @jameslarge But i told u to check out the internals of `newCachedThreadPool` and I thought that you will conclude that creating `new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (...)` is the way to go - where insteed of Integer.MAX_VALUE you would use thread limit.  Here is some SO about this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800317/impossible-to-make-a-cached-thread-pool-with-a-size-limit